# Error: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby, string, methods, hash, integer

Can anyone tell me why I am receiving this error for the code below?

```
def total_single_order(one_order)
  single_order_totals = Hash.new(0)
  one_order.each do |coffee_sku, coffee_info_hash|
    binding.pry
    single_order_totals[coffee_sku]['cost_to_customer'] = (coffee_info_hash["RetailPrice"].to_f * coffee_info_hash['num_bags]'].to_f)
    single_order_totals[coffee_sku]['cost_to_company'] = (coffee_info_hash["PurchasingPrice"].to_f * coffee_info_hash['num_bags]'].to_f)
  end
  single_order_totals
end

total_single_order(one_order)
```

Comment: Did you transcribe the code correctly?  As shown, this code should generate an error `Undefined method [] for nil` on the line that assigns to `single_order_totals[coffee_sku]['cost_to_customer']`? Please show the exact error an identify the line at the top of the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Peter. After making the typo error corrections in order to get this to work I had to initialize like so: single_order_totals =  Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on lines 5 and 6, in addition to the problem mentioned in the comment above.

```
coffee_info_hash['num_bags]']
```

looks like it should be

```
coffee_info_hash['num_bags']
```

Also, `single_order_totals[coffee_sku]` evaluates to zero since `single_order_totals` is initialized with a default value of zero in `Hash.new(0)`.

The error you're getting seems to be coming from

```
coffee_info_hash["RetailPrice"]
```

Presumably all your SKUs are integers. So you're actually trying to access 'RetailPrice' on an integer here.

An analogous example:

```
sku = 45
sku["key"]
#=> in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Comment: Thanks @jmromer. I made the type changes and also found out that I needed to initialize the single_order_totals = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] } in order to get the rest of it to work